# Where are the headers with IOCTL numbers for ext4?

Tags: filesystem, programming, ext4, development, c

I am looking for [`ext4.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h), or another file that contains `EXT4_IOC_*`. There is nothing in `/usr/include` or `/usr/src`. I have `linux-headers-generic` installed. I am on Kubuntu 14.10. Where are the headers?

*Edit:* Using [Ubuntu Package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ext4.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=utopic&arch=any), there are definitely no packages that contain the correct ext4.h. Mysterious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some* of the `EXT4_IOC_` definitions appear to be exposed via `/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2_fs.h`, which is supplied by the package `e2fslibs-dev`.

To obtain the actual `ext4.h` header AFAIK you will need to download the kernel **source** package, rather than just the kernel headers: either by enabling source repositories and then executing something like

```
apt-get source linux-image-`uname -r`
```

or by checking it out directly from the git repository. You should then find `ext4.h` in the `fs/ext4` subdirectory:

```
find linux-3.2.0/ -name 'ext4.h'
linux-3.2.0/fs/ext4/ext4.h
linux-3.2.0/include/trace/events/ext4.h
```

**However you probably shouldn't be relying on kernel source headers if you are writing user-space code** - if something's not exposed via the regular development package or kernel headers, then you shouldn't be using it outside of the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, that is comprehensive and helpful! I was specifically wanting EXT4_IOC_SWAP_BOOT, as I am playing about with OS development, and wanted to use that facility for my bootloader - so not a normal user-space program! AFAIK, GRUB doesn't use EXT4_IOC_SWAP_BOOT yet (though they have plans to), so that may be why it's not exposed yet.